# How to validate a string with spaces?

Tags: python

Currently I have this, but when entering a name with a surname, but it does not validate it accordingly

```
name = input("Enter your name: ")
if True == name.isalnum():
    print("Correct, it's a name")
else:
    print("Error")
```

Comment: I think your best bet would be to use Regex here. You could check for alpha numeric characters as well as special characters like periods.

Comment: Read this one https://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/

Comment: Can you clarify what exactly the issue is?

Comment: My first name officially includes a whitespace character!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to split the input by space symbols first and then check each part. The code will be something like that:

```py
name = input("Enter your name: ")
if all(part.isalnum for part in name.split()):
    print("Correct, it's a name")
else:
    print("Error")
```

Btw, I guess you should use `isalpha` instead of `isalnum`, because '123' not seems to be a valid name.

Comment: use `name.split(' ') ` pass space as an argument to split to avoid accepting other white space symbols. It might fail for initial with full stop or apostrophe

Comment: @Serge that's a valid point, if you don't consider tabs as valid space symbols in your input you should use `name.split(" ")` in the code above. And if you want the maximum 1 space allowed use `name.split(sep=" ", maxsplit=1)`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should change your code checking for if all are digits

```
False == name.isdigit():
```